# Approximate Lebesgue measure functions by simple functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function.

I know that if $f$ is non-negative then we can approximate $f$ by a sequence of simple functions.

But I came across the statement " every Lebesgue measurable function is equal almost everywhere to a limit of simple Lebesgue measurable functions".

I'm not sure why this holds if $f$ is negative.

Thanks!

Comment: $f = f^{+} - f_{-}$, where $f^{+} = \max\{f,0\}$ and $f^{-} = \max\{-f,0\}$.  Take a sequence of simple functions converging to $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$.  (If necessary, use the fact that $\{f > 0\}$ and $\{f < 0\}$ are both Lebesgue measurable.)

Comment: We have that $f  = f^+ - f^-$ where $f^+ = \max{f, 0}$ and $f^-=\max{-f,0}$. Let $\{h_n\}_n$ be a sequence of simple function converging almost everywhere to $f^+$ and  let $\{k_n\}_n$ be a sequence of simple function converging almost everywhere to $f^-$. It folows that $\{h_n-k_n\}_n$  is a a sequence of simple function converging almost everywhere to $f^+- f^-$, that means, converging almost everywhere to $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $f  = f^+ - f^-$ where $f^+ = \max{f, 0}$ and $f^-=\max{-f,0}$. Note that since $f$ is measurable, we have that $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable.

Let $\{h_n\}_n$ be a sequence of simple function converging almost everywhere to $f^+$ and  let $\{k_n\}_n$ be a sequence of simple function converging almost everywhere to $f^-$. It folows that $\{h_n-k_n\}_n$  is a a sequence of simple function converging almost everywhere to $f^+- f^-$, that means, converging almost everywhere to $f$.